# Does publishing in non-prestigious journal damage your portfolio

Tags: publications, journals, writing

**Context**
A year ago, I had a desire to write my first article for a journal. Since I hadn't had much experience in scientific writing, I gave up writing it. However, I've recently found this work and realized that it could actually be slightly modified to meet the academic writing format.

The work is not a scientific breakthrough but not rubbish either (at least I think so because nobody has conducted such an experiment so far, so, perhaps, it will be novel). I expect that I can be admitted to like Q3 or Q4 journal if I edit it properly.

**Question**
At this point, I start wondering whether I should try to publish it in, let's say, a "not-very-cool" journal or forget it? On one hand, the more articles, the better for a resume. On the other hand, wouldn't  the fact that people see that I'm published in low-quality journals some how affect me badly?

Note. I understand that the questions needs more specifics to be properly answered, but I'd like to hear maybe from those experienced how academia works...

Comment: @Sursula-they-, that's what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a first publication don't overthink it. Something is better than nothing as long as you avoid predatory journals.

Among other things you will get experience in the publication process and in responding to reviewers. But only if you submit it.

If you don't take the first step you don't get anywhere. If this were your 15th publication and all were in low impact journals then there might be some issues.

You can also aim a bit higher for a first submission. If your work is really not appropriate for a journal you are likely to get rejected pretty quickly and you can then submit elsewhere.

Just. Do. It.

Comment: Thank you for motivation! Btw, how do peolple know that the journal is not predatory ?

Comment: Search on this site for "Beale's list" for some ideas about predatory journals. They have some characteristics, though: soliciting articles, high publication charges, poor reviewing, very high acceptance rates. But those are, to some extent, features of quality journals too, though not all in combination.